# Nested divs and floats not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a three column page. My intention is to have 2 main sections:

- Left hand section (this will be split into two columns)
- Right hand section (this will have onlly one column)

Columns 1 and 2 float left correctly and are side by side. However, I have tried just about everything, and column 3 ALWAYS is displayed under column 1&2

This is what my simplified HTML looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <style type="text/css">
          body { width: 1200px; }
          .spacer { clear: both; height: 1px; }
          #lhs-section, #rhs-section { float: left; }
          #col1, #col2, #col3 { float: left; min-height: 400px; padding-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #abc; width: 350px; }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="lhs-section">
                <div id="col1"></div>
                <div id="col2"></div>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rhs-section">
                <div id="col3"></div>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean problem with your `id names` they are different in `css` & in `html` `markup`. Reason you write `#lhs-section`, `#rhs-section` in your css & `<div id="lhs_section">` `<div id="rhs_section">`
in your html.

So, write like this:

```
<div id="lhs-section">
                <div id="col1"></div>
                <div id="col2"></div>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rhs-section">
                <div id="col3"></div>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/aU5y8/

Comment: sandeep: Sorry, that was a typo. I have corrected the html in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `<div class="spacer"></div>` in lhs_section

```
 <html>
    <head>
       <style type="text/css">
          .spacer { clear: both; height: 1px; }
          #lhs_section, #rhs_section { float: left; }
          #col1, #col2, #col3 { float: left; min-height: 400px; padding-right: 5px; border: 1px solid #abc; width: 350px; }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="lhs_section">
                <div id="col1"></div>
                <div id="col2"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rhs_section">
                <div id="col3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rohan, can you explain why I have to remove the "spacer" div?. I have always used a "rough rule" that whenever you have nested divs, to use a spacer to seperate them from the container. Sometimes this works - other times (like in this case), it dosen't work - so when is it required to use the spacer (I see you did not remove them all) - what is the logic - or was it trial and error?

Comment: Always divide your webpage in three section header,main content and footer.you can divide the main content in columns.there is not necessary to use spacer between columns.you can use spacer between header,main content and footer.Sorry I forgot to remove spacer in rhs section.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spacer div after col1 and col2

Here's a jsfiddle link to the corrected code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mwESj/

Comment: can you explain why you removed that particular "spacer" div?. I have always used a "rough rule" that whenever you have nested divs, to use a spacer to seperate them from the container. Sometimes this works - other times (like in this case), it dosen't work - so when is it required to use the spacer (I see you did not remove them all) - what is the logic - or was it trial and error?